# How to configure jenkins to build and run spring boot project periodically?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins

I have spring boot application(maven build) and I want to configure Jenkins to pull code from GitHub and build project, finally run the project and stop building while the application is still running. This process has to occur every 2 hour, but the last run should terminate.
So far I have tried:

```
schtasks /delete /tn CMS /f
@echo off
setlocal

set minute=%time:~3,2%
set /A minute+=1
set tasktime=%time:~0,2%:%minute%:%time:~6,2%

schtasks /create /tn CMS /tr "mvn clean spring-boot:run" /sc once /st %tasktime%
```

As post build action.
Note that the OS is windows.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normal SCM Trigger in Jenkins. With something like that:

- */2 * * *